# how to give link to a file to the folder within the subfolder using anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net

Im having the following files with this folder structure.

**Home.aspx**

**folder1:
  |-->Page1.aspx**

**Subfolder1:
    |-->Page2.aspx**

**Subfolder1A:
     |-->Page3.aspx**

I want to link the aspx files using the anchor tag.
i tried like this.

```
 <a href="/Home.aspx">Home</a>  ---->for linking the home page

<a href="/folder1/Page1.aspx">Page1</a> --->for linking the page1

<a href="../folder1/Subfolder1/Page2.aspx">Page2</a> --for linking the page2

<a href="../folder1/Subfolder1/Subfolder1A/Page3.aspx">Page3</a>-for linking the page3
```

could any help me to understanding the linking of files with the subfolder.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mention about the path in html.

`/` stand for the root of the current drive;

`./` stand for the current directory;

`../` stand for the parent of the current directory.